# Why is my map() function in react.js not working?

Tags: reactjs, map-function

When I try to run this code it returns "TypeError: state.drinksData.map is not a function". However, when I type manually the index (as *state.drinksData[0]*) it works fine. Why is that and how can I fix it?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

var initialState = {
    drinksData: ""
}


function LoadDrinks(props) {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);


    //Fetching the cocktails' data from the ingredient clicked
    function pageReload(e){
        fetch(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=${e.target.value}`)
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>{
            setState({drinksData:data.drinks})
        })   
    }
    
   
    console.log(state.drinksData)
    
    var drinkData = state.drinksData.map(data=>{return(data)});
    //However, this code runs fine when I type the index manually --> drinkData = state.drinksData[0]; 
    var ingredients = ["Gin", "Vodka", "Rum", "Whiskey", "Tequila", "Brandy"];

    return (
        <>
            <select onChange={pageReload}>
                {ingredients.map((ingredient, i)=>{return (<option key={i}>{ingredient}</option>)})}
            </select>
            <div>{drinkData.strDrink}</div>
        </>
    )
} 

export default LoadDrinks;
```

This is part of my first React project. I appreciate your help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix the types of values in state when possible, otherwise you can get errors like these. You initially set `drinksData` to a *string*, but the value given by the API in `data.drinks` is an *array*.

Initialize the initial state to an empty array, not a string. (You can't `.map` strings, hence the error.)

```
const initialState = {
    drinksData: []
};
```

Also, the line here

```
var drinkData = state.drinksData.map(data=>{return(data)});
```

is completely superfluous: it creates a new array that's exactly the same as the old array. Feel free to remove it entirely and just keep using `state.drinksData`.

`strDrink` is a property of one of the *objects* in the array - it's not a property of the array, so `drinkData.strDrink` or `state.drinkData.strDrink` won't work. If you want to get to one of the object's `strDrink`s, iterate over the array, eg

```
state.drinksData.map(obj => obj.strDrink)
```

Lastly, since you're using hooks, there's no reason to have an extra nested object in state. It'd be easier for the state to be just a plain array:

```
const [drinks, setDrinks] = useState([]);
```

and

```
function pageReload(e){
    fetch(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=${e.target.value}`)
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>{
        setDrinks(data.drinks);
    })
    // .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget to catch possible errors
}
```